# C# Pass to function a Child List as a Base List

Tags: c#, list, polymorphism, parameter-passing, covariance

I have a base type B and multiple derived child types, C1:B, C2:B, C3:B, etc.

I have lists of each child type, ListL1, ListL2, ListL3.

I have working functions, F1, F2, F3, for each child type that take the corresponding list, L1, L2, L3, for that child and accomplish what is essentially the same functionality (dealing only with B's properties) but for the corresponding type, C1, C2, C3.

I wish to have a single function, based on a list of the base type, List "polymorphically" perform the function indepent of the type of the child.

I know that I should be able to pass the list into my function by in-fixing my function declaration with the template specifier, something like:

```
public void Fn<T>(List<T> BList) { /* do stuff */ }
```

I want each of my child functions, F1, F2, F3, to call the Base function, something like

```
public void F1(List<C1> L1)
{
     Fn(L1);  // this is the line that fails
}
```

I've tried recasting as the base type, B

```
Fn( (List<B>)L1 );
```

but, I get an error saying that I can't convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List' even though C1 was derived from B.

I've also tried infixing the type in the Fn name:

```
Fn<C1>( L1 );

Fn<C1>(  (List<B>)L1 );
```

I've found recommendations saying that I should cast my child list as a base class list (which fails for me) and within my generic function, Fn, check whether my passed list is of a specific type, then perform separate code specific to that type.  Besides the casting not working for me as recommended, that seems to defeat the polymorphism of OOP to still have child class specific code within the generic function.

I'm hopeful that there exists some true abstract/generic means by which to not repeat the code and thereby treat my child lists as base lists.

Can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read this article first: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

In short, even if `C : B`, `List<C>` cannot be referenced as `List<B>`, **but** `IEnumerable<>` can (read the above article to understand why).

Then you can use:

```
public void Fn(IEnumerable<B> BList) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IList` instead of `List`. Check [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

Comment: `IList` is still not a `Covariant`.